# Уместно ли не закрывать файл сразу после прочтения данных?

Tags: c++, файлы

Я открываю файл в С++ (F.open(put);). Далее я читаю оттуда данные, и после этого я уже не использую файл, но я хочу, чтобы до завершения работы программы этот файл никто не смог бы редактировать, кроме моей программы.
Можно ли в этом случае просто не закрывать файл до окончания работы программы, или в этом есть какие-то свои подводные камни?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Взаимодействие с объектами операционной системы зависят от операционной системы. Файлы - объекты операционной системы. Все упирается в средства, которыми Вы взаимодействуете с оперционной системой, позволяют ли они тонко настраивать, или нет. Любые библиотеки (boost.filesystem или базовые средства языка, или что-то еще) - являются обертками над функциями операционной системы для взаимодействия с файлами.

В Windows есть функция [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx), которая позволяет управлять, будет ли файл доступен сторонним приложениям, или нет. Аналогичное есть (должно быть :) ) в любой операционной системе. Хорошие обертки над функциями ОС или тоже позволяют это настраивать, или, для реализации единообразности взаимодействия с разными ОС, немного урезают функционал, оставляя только то, что поддерживается большинством ОС.

Лично я `F.Open` не узнаю, т.е. не могу судить об этой библиотеке.

Отвечая на вопрос: ничто не мешает Вашему ПО создавать объект ядра с теми настройками владения, какие Вам нужны, и держать его, сколько необходимо.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше сразу закрывать всегда, как только прекращаете работу с файлом.
Я не уверена, но думаю, что его всё равно смогут редактировать, даже если он не закрыт.       Проведите простой опыт: запустите программу в отладке и до f.close() попытайтесь открыть его вручную, изменить и сохранить эти изменения, и вы найдёте ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Это не так.

Comment: @smallFish: Какие системы, кроме Винды, по умолчанию не позволяют редактировать файл, открытый другими процессами? Обычно, нужны специальные приёмы, чтобы избежать повреждения файла, если он редактируется сразу несколькими процессами одновременно.

Comment: @jfs, вроде бы, если файловая система примонтирована соответствующим образом, функция fcntl(...) из linux API позволяет устанавливать блокировки.

Comment: @smallFish: какой механизм используется для блокировки файла не существенно (их несколько существует и большинство методов требуют кооперации от других процессов), важно что простое открытие файла по умолчанию его не активирует